# Configuration not working in String STS

Tags: spring-boot

I am facing two problem while setuping up enviroment in my windows7.

**Problem #1)**
 When running Spring-Boot-version 1.5.3 , I am getting error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at com.example.MongodbdemoApplication.main(MongodbdemoApplication.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

**My Solution:**

When I change the version to 1.4.6 its working fine. Even After googling I am not able to find the problem.

**Problem 2)** 
Spring Boot version : 1.4.6

My complete code is in `com.example` package. But in the `RestController`class is not able to wire the `PersonRepository` class. Code is as below.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
```

**Controller Class:**

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repo;

}
```

** PersonRepository:**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;


public interface PersonRepository  extends MongoRepository<Person, String>{

}
```

** AddressRepository:**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface AddressRepository extends MongoRepository<Address, Integer> {    
}
```

**Main Application class:**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.*"})
public class MongodbdemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MongodbdemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error Logs:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repo in com.example.PersonController required a bean of type 'com.example.PersonRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.PersonRepository' in your configuration.
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodbdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mongodbdemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Steps Tried adding `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})` which doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: When you have an error with 1.5.3 downgrading is hardly a solution. I suspect you have a corrupted jar in your repository. Run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to clean the repository. Also adding `@ComponentScan` in this case will change nothing as that is already defined in `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right after clearing the jar its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution to Problem 1 and Problem 2**

As commented by Mr. Deinum comments my jar are corrupted, So I deleted the .m2 folder and build the project again. This time its working fine.

Its not related with my sts configration its related with jar which are corrupted.